# Encrypted Titles

Tags: cipher, movies

Let's keep this movie train rolling! Below are a handful of Academy Award Best Picture winning movie titles, but each has been encrypted somehow. There is a common rule determining the encryption methods. Can you determine what each title is and how it was encrypted?

#### Titles

> BUO QVRHT PW WHF FHSUNUN GARNU
>
> PO CVWNTYA FOY QLD TGN
>
> MJCTFWIG PO GTBKOC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*BUO QVRHT PW WHF FHSUNUN GARNU* decrypts as:

> **ALL QUIET ON THE WESTERN FRONT**

*PO CVWNTYA FOY QLD TGN* decrypts as:

> **NO COUNTRY FOR OLD MEN**

*MJCTFWIG PO GTBKOC* decrypts as:

> **LAWRENCE OF ARABIA**

The encryption algorithm is:

> Rotate all non-space letters by the year the movie was produced.
>  `in:   ALL QUIET ON THE WESTERN FRONT`
>  `salt: 193 01930 19 301 9301930 19301`
>  `out:  BUO QVRHT PW WHF FHSUNUN GARNU`
>
>  `in:   NO COUNTRY FOR OLD MEN`
>  `salt: 20 0720072 007 200 720`
>  `out:  PO CVWNTYA FOY QLD TGN`
>
>  `in:   LAWRENCE OF ARABIA`
>  `salt: 19621962 19 621962`
>  `out:  MJCTFWIG PO GTBKOC`
>
>  I'm sure there's a name for this kind of cypher. Someone can probably help me out with that.

I came to this conclusion by

> first figuring out the names of the movies by the number of letters in each word. Once I had that, I ran a short little script that gave me the difference between each letter as a number.
>
> ```
> def f(a, b):
>   d = []
>   for c in xrange(len(a)):
>     if a[c] == ' ':
>       continue
>     d += [(ord(a[c])-ord(b[c])+26)%26]
>   return d
> ```
>
> The numbers that came back were sequences of the same four digits repeated over and over. I checked these digits against the release dates, and they matched.

Comment: Fantastic, how did that salt occur to you?

Comment: Well, *[redacted]*. Added within the answer so it can be hidden.

Comment: Thinking its something related to a Vigenaire-Chiffre

Comment: Nicely done Ian! Solved singlehandedly. Well deserved

Comment: It's called a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Description)

Comment: This particular version is the Gronsfeld cipher.